# Download csv file from NSE

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, stock

i want to download csv file from https://www1.nseindia.com/products/content/derivatives/equities/historical_fo.htm .

input: different options.
output: automatic download of csv file

unable to get link generated by csv file and Trying to download red-highlighted csv file using python.

[image: see the image here]

```
   import requests
import pandas as pd

query = {  # just mimicking sample query that I saw after loading link
'instrumentType': 'OPTSTK',
'symbol': 'SBIN',
'expiryDate':'26-12-2019', #'select',
'optionType': 'CE',
'strikePrice': '',
'dateRange': '',
'fromDate': '02-12-2019',
'toDate': '25-12-2019',
'segmentLink': '9',
'symbolCount': '',
}

headers = {
    'Pragma': 'no-cache',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'Referer': 'https://www.nseindia.com/products/content/derivatives/equities/historical_fo.htm',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
}



url = 'https://www.nseindia.com/products/dynaContent/common/productsSymbolMapping.jsp?\
instrumentType=%s\
&symbol=%s\
&expiryDate=%s\
&optionType=%s\
&strikePrice=%s\
&dateRange=%s\
&fromDate=%s\
&toDate=%s\
&segmentLink=%s\
&symbolCount=%s' %(query['instrumentType'],
  query['symbol'],
  query['expiryDate'],
  query['optionType'],
  query['strikePrice'],
  query['dateRange'],
  query['fromDate'],
  query['toDate'],
  query['segmentLink'],
  query['symbolCount']
  )

response = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
```

now print url and paste in browser...i am getting very less data.

Comment: Post some code, perhaps.

Also, that "file" might not exist unless you submit the form.

Comment: Question updated with relevant code.

Comment: The code is pointing towards new NSE website. New website may be using dynamic link generation. There may be a function something like generateLink('button id') or so. Try copy pasting highlighted link in raw text editor.

Answer (score 0):

To replay the clicks and download the data, you must use Selenium or a similar package.